# CSS: Trying to test behavior of flex-shrink but can't see it working

Tags: css, flexbox

I have 3 flex boxes in a row.  On the first one, class `.one`, I have `flex: 1 1 400px`.  I thought that would allow the box that is set to 400px be able to shrink but it's stayed at 400px when I lower the screen width.
I also see no difference when I do `flex: 1 0 400px` .

```css
div.cont {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

div > div {
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  background: green;
}

.one {
  background: green;
  flex: 1 1 400px;
}

.two {
  background: blue;
  flex: 1;
}

.three {
  background: pink;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>  
  <div class="three"></div>  
</div>
```

Comment: it doesn't stay at 400px, if the container is less than 400px it will have less than 400px